# Saving a file in notepad (AutoIT)

Tags: autoit

I'm trying to write a script that writes a file in notepad and then saves it.
The end of the code looks like this:

```
WinClose("Untitled - Notepad")
WinWaitActive("Notepad", "Save")
Send("{ENTER}")
WinWaitActive("Notepad", "Save As")
Send("CurrentJob.job{ENTER}")
```

It works, except for that the file gets the name "rentJob.job" rather than "currentJob.job".
I guess this comes from not properly waiting for 'Save As' to open, but how do you do that?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to grab the contents of the notepad window, then just write it directly to the file. Much less error prone because you don't need to wait for any windows.

```
$title = "Untitled - Notepad"

$text = ControlGetText($title, "", "[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:1]") ; Get the text
FileWrite("./CurrentJob.job", $text) ; Write the text to file
WinKill($title) ; Close the window and ignore all dialog prompts
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a notepad to write a txt file.

This code will write a text file.

```
FileWrite("CurrentJob.job", "This is my text file!" & @CRLF & "This is a second line")
```